# mapping between sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $f$ is a mapping between two sets $A$ and $B$ and if $ a\in A $ and $f(a)=a$ what is that called? I looked though some Abstract Algebra books but couldn't recall.

Comment: are you saying $A\subset B$?  and $f(a)=a$ for all $a\in A$?

Comment: thats a good question in this case it would be B is a subset of A

Comment: Well that is a single element that maps to itself and not too unusual.  If every element of $A$ is mapped to itself then the function (restricted to $A$) is called the identity function.  We *could* say $f$ restricted to $\{a\}$ is the identity function but that'd be a little ... disingenuous.  I don't know if there is a term for it.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner that $A\subset B$ is certainly a requirement for such a mapping to be well defined.  I read the question as asking for the usual name of such a mapping.  @ thestar you do not need for $B$ to be a subset of $A$ in this case.

Comment: Are you saying *every* element of $A$ is mapped to itself (which requires that $A\subset B$) or are you just saying that $a$ is *one* element that maps to itself (and other elements of $A$ do not map to themselves?

Comment: @fleablood, that is exactly it I am saying only some are mapped to themselves

Comment: Well... in that case... it doesn't have a canonical name.  It is "a mapping with at least one fixed point."

Comment: @JMoravitz  Bingo.... Cat got  my tongue.  But "fixed point" is the   *exact* terminology for this point. Completely slipped out of my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(a) = a$ that's called a "fixed point".

It is usually assumed that $f: X\to X$ but that isn't necessary.  It is necessary that $a \in A\cap B$ and $A\cap B \ne \emptyset$ though.

Answer (score 2):

The mapping from $A$ to $B$ such that $f(a)=a$ for all $a\in A$ is known as [the inclusion map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_map) from $A$ to $B$

It often receives the symbol $\iota$ and that it goes from $A$ to $B$ is often written as $A\hookrightarrow B$ with a `\hookrightarrow`

---

From the comments, it seems you are not talking about the *mapping* but rather the point(s) $a$ such that $f(a)=a$ and are not requiring that all $a$ satisfy $f(a)=a$.  These are called "[fixed points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics))."

Comment: For clarity:  This assumes that $f(A) = A$ and $A\subset B$, correct?  (And this is interpreting the OP's question as for *every* $a \in A$ that $f(a) = a$?)

Comment: Yes, I interpreted it as for every $a\in A$ we have $f(a)=a$.  A result of that is that $f(A)=A$ and that $A\subset B$ though these weren't one of the assumptions made, but rather conclusions.

Comment: You're right.  I meant: "This assumes $A\subset B$ (otherwise $f(a) = a$ for all $a \in A$ would not be possible)"